# jQuery Mobile with dual range slider

Tags: jquery-mobile, slider

I try to have a dual range slider on website mobile version using two sliders like in this post :

[jQuery Mobile dual range slider working but buggy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9237191/jquery-mobile-dual-range-slider-working-but-buggy)

It works great but I have just one problem when I load the first page I have no problem but when I go to another page and go back to my first page it keeps my first range limits.

Example :

First page a slider with value min to 0 and value max to 100, if I put min slider to 40 and I try to slide the max under 40 it stops to 40, it's ok. But when I change page and go back I can't slide the min slide after 40 and the max slider under 40 (it keeps the value where the conflict was) !

If someone can help me to understand it would be great !
Thanks,
Alex

Comment: Question is already answered


[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9237191/jquery-mobile-dual-range-slider-working-but-buggy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9237191/jquery-mobile-dual-range-slider-working-but-buggy)