# Getting a dual range slider working with twitter bootstrap

Tags: jquery-mobile, twitter-bootstrap

I'd like to use this upgraded jQuery Mobile dual range slider.
[jQuery Mobile dual range slider working but buggy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9237191/jquery-mobile-dual-range-slider-working-but-buggy/13259790#13259790)

I need to use it with twitter bootstrap.  However, jQuery Mobile doesn't play nice with Twitter bootstrap and is killing the dropdown menu when the javaScript files are placed at the bottom of the page (as per yslow).  Here are 3 jsbin examples to illustrate the problem:

with jQuery Mobile added, twitter bootstrap menu fails:
    http://jsbin.com/ibecox/1

without jQuery Mobile .js file, twitter bootstrap the menu works fine:
    http://jsbin.com/ibecox/2

with all javaScript in the header (bad practice) the menu also works, but I'd need to avoid putting all the javaScript in the header:
    http://jsbin.com/ibecox/3

Comment: Have the same issue while using slider. Twitter bootstrap doesn't work with jQuery UI.

Answer (score 0):

I can see there's a broken link to the twitter bootstrap js, I've fixed it and your sample works fine for me, both the dropdown menu and the progress bar

Comment: Hi Sergiy,  thanks for noticing that.  jsFiddle was producing the same error as my real page so I didn't notice that they were happening for different reasons.  I've updated my question to include a jsBin that looks closer to my real page and illustrates the problem correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If all you're trying to do is get jquerymobile's [Range Slider](https://api.jquerymobile.com/rangeslider/#entry-examples) to work with Bootstrap, you can use the [Custom Download tool](http://jquerymobile.com/download-builder/) to download just the slice that (sort of) makes the Range Slider work.

What you get is unfortunately incomplete, and above all it doesn't self-initialize, so you'll need to do that manually:

```
$('div[data-role=rangeslider]').rangeslider();
```

And you'll need to apply some styles of your own to make up for a bit too much being left out in the custom download. But you will get Range Sliders without breaking Bootstrap.

The cause of the Bootstrap break when you use all of jquery mobile is more complex. The Init module applies a ton of classes all over your code, in particular .ui-btn to buttons. That's the main thing that blows up Bootstrap - the nav menu uses a button tag, and that tag gets that problematic class applied, and then in come all the problem styles from jquerymobile.

The hackier way to solve that in the large is to just use jquerymobile without the Init module then Init only what you need - hopefully their buttons aren't one of those things. The best way to solve it is pretty intense: Improve jquerymobile so that there's either no conflict with Bootstrap ever, or, some sort of special noBSconflict() method or something you can run that avoids applying classes that will break Bootstrap but otherwise proceeds as normal.